# What is MauiContext and how to get one in .NET MAUI project?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, platform

I am trying to write a custom method for showing native dialog fragment on Android containing the MAUI ContentPage. I am using a partial class with partial method for that:

```
public partial void ShowCustomDialog(ContentPage contentPage)
{
    if (contentPage.ToPlatform(-MauiContext-) is Android.Views.View androidView)
    {
        var customDialogFragment = new CustomDialogFragment();

        if (customDialogFragment != null && Platform.CurrentActivity is Activity currentActivity)
        {
            customDialogFragment.Container.AddView(androidView);
            customDialogFragment.Show(currentActivity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that the IElementToPlatform() method takes MauiContex as an argument, but I have no idea what is that, and how to recieve one?

I found only one example here: https://vladislavantonyuk.azurewebsites.net/articles/Creating-a-bottom-sheet-using-.NET-MAUI

But problem is that when I am trying to get the MauiContext from the Handler of the view (in my example the ContentPage), the Handler of that view is always null.

Do you have any relevant info about the MauiContext and how to implement it right in my solution please?

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create), it talks about custom control.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT this is actually not even close to the problem I am dealing with here.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can see this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73382692/custom-maui-handler-control-creates-handler-when-used-in-xaml-but-when-created-w), and the following answer mentions how to get MauiContext. It could be helpful to you.

Comment: How does one use ToPlatform(context)? This is one of those cases where the docs are... lacking...

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MauiContext is the object in the handler of your MAUI application contains the Context for your application. For example by which you can resolve your DI registered objects etc in your application

To get the MauiContext in ContentPage of your application you can get the object by overriding the OnHandlerChanged method which comes from Element Class.

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
    base.OnHandlerChanged();
    var context = this.Handler.MauiContext;
}
```